# jQuery Previous and Forward issue

Tags: jquery

I am beginner in jQuery.

I have three boxes. Every box has its own Prev/Next navigation. When I click on any box, text move, which is fine. But when I click on Prev/Next navigation (except first one) it doesn’t move. Please guide me how can I fix that?

Please check the example to understand my requirement in a better way.

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/nWqGf/1/

Thanks

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id`. That's a good place to start...

Comment: ID should be unique. You have duplicate ID for next and prev links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned the same Id to multiple elements, which is a major problem. Instead, what you should do is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nWqGf/9/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same id's multiple times. You should use a class for those buttons, and another attribute to relate it with the correct box.

I've modified your jsFiddle, and now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/nWqGf/11/

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique, You cannot have duplicate ID's. I modified your markup and then updated the script like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/nWqGf/6/)

**JS:**

```
$(".gallery-prev").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".scroll").data("scrollable").prev();
    });

$(".gallery-next").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().find(".scroll").data("scrollable").next();
    });
});
```

**HTML:** (Changed all ID to class)

```
<a href="#" class="gallery-prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" class="gallery-next">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/vGnuS/

JavaScript (only one line):

```
$(".scroll").scrollable({ circular: true });​
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
    <br />
    <div class="scroll">
        <div class="pics">
            <div>box 1</div>
            <div>box 2</div>
            <div>box 3</div>
            <div>box 4</div>
            <div>box 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
    <br />    
    <div class="scroll">
        <div class="pics">
            <div>box 6</div>
            <div>box 7</div>
            <div>box 8</div>
            <div>box 9</div>
            <div>box 10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
    <br />

    <div class="scroll">
        <div class="pics">
            <div>box 11</div>
            <div>box 12</div>
            <div>box 13</div>
            <div>box 14</div>
            <div>box 15</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```